# Convert Screen Distance to Eye Space Ray Distance

Tags: opengl, graphics

I have a ray with an origin (x,y,z) and a direction (dx, dy, dz) given in homogeneous eye space coordinates:

p = (x,y,z,1) + t * (dx, dy, dz, 0)

What I need to calculate is a *positive* value for t that for a given pixel distance n results in a point n pixels away from the screen projection of (x,y,z). How can I achieve this?

Regards

Comment: What are "homogeneous eye space coordinates" After or before projected coordinates from the view?

Comment: Regular eye space coordinates. After camera transform, before perspective projection. If it makes things simpler, we can assume that the ray is given in clip coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

Projecting a point into a plane is obtaining the intersection with this plane of the ray through the point and with the direction of the view. Let's say that view direction is vector v.

Put the origin of your ray (let's call it O{x,y,z}) in the line from the camera perpendicular to the near plane of projection. Let's call its projection P. Then a second point (that you expressed as S=O+t·d) will project into the near plane at point T. You need 't' that makes distance PT = n.

If you do the cross product `c = vxd` you get a distance in near plane. Remember `vxd= |v||d|sin(a)`. If both v and d are normalized that distance is the sin of the angle between v and d.

If d is not normalized (dnn), i.e. |d|=distance(O,S), then the distance between O and S after projection on near plane is `k= cross(dnn,d)` which is `= distance(O,S)·cross(v,d) = t·cross(v,d)`. Making the required value, n, same as k `n= k` results in `t= n / cross(v,d)` with both v,d normalized.

Using pixels instead of values in the near plane is just a matter of scaling properly with window sizes.